# Is a totally ordered, separable and connected topological space metrizable (in the order topology)?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is a totally ordered, separable and connected topological space metrizable (in the order topology)?

If we relax the assumption of connectedness, I know the counterexamples, but if we have a linear continuum that is also separable, can we say it is metrizable?

Thanks!

Comment: Crossposted to math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3534793/is-a-totally-ordered-separable-and-connected-topological-space-metrizable-in-t

Comment: See my answer on math stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3535931/4280).

Comment: E.g. the so-called [double arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) is a classic separable non-metrisable compact LOTS.

Comment: @WholeFood, I rolled your edit back to the previous version because the post was too cryptic in the modified version, whereas the original one is more easily readable. For instance, I had no idea what the acronym "LOTS" was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because it is regular and has a countable base, namely the family of open intervals with the ends at the dense countable set. The connectedness guarantees that each open interval $(a,b)$ is not empty and hence contains a point from the countable dense set.

Comment: Metrizable? Isn't the space described in the question homeomorphic to an interval of the real line?

Comment: Yes, it is. But anyway some argument for proving this is necessary. Without connectedness you have a non-metrizable example of the double arrow space.

Comment: The general condition for LOTS's is having a $G_\delta$ diagonal or a $\sigma$-locally countable base. Theory from the 1970's when LOTS's where studied more.